# How to write ls command if i am trying to search these 3 files only

Tags: unix

How to write ls -lrt  command if I am trying to search these 3 files ONLY

Example -
fileabc85.txt
fileabc91.txt
fileabc121.tct

Answer (score 1):

`ls -ltr fileabc85.txt fileabc91.txt fileabc121.tct`